# Loading Unicode Characters from XML and push into Form via AJAX

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, unicode

How can I load Unicode Characters (specifically a trademark symbol) from XML and push it into a Form via AJAX?

When I push formelement.value += "\u2122" it works fine, but when I place "\u2122" into XML, load it via AJAX, and push it to the form element it does not work.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It should work if you use UTF-8 to encode the XML document. Otherwise try to use a character reference like `&#x2122;`.

Answer (score 0):

That's a javascript format; javascript understands it and converts it to the appropriate character, but the XML parser does not.  Instead of '\u2122' use '™' in XML.

Comment: Your the second person that suggested this, but I can't get it to work.  I'm 99% sure everything is UTF-8, but it's not working.  Any chance you can get an example running?

Thanks,
Colin

Comment: I'll see about producing a working sample.  In the meantime, what are you doing with the posted data?  How are you verifying that it doesn't work?

Comment: Was that an attempt to put AMP - # - x 2122 SEMI into the answer? It is showing as the actual TM symbol.